# How to avoid/control creation of default security group rule when creating kubernetes LoadBalancer service in Azure?

Tags: azure, kubernetes

Whenever I create Nginx ingress controller with kubernetes service of type LoadBalancer, it adds rules 500/501 the LoadBalancer security group that opens 80 and 443 to internet.

Is there a way to prevent this or change these rules?

Comment: You want an internal LoadBalancer?

Comment: No. Upon creation, my load balancer is assigned with an existing security group that has some IP whitelisting rules.  I want to keep those rule and prevent creation of the default 500/501 rules.

Comment: Are your rules on the subnet level? Subnet nsg takes precedence.

Comment: What about now?

Comment: Have had the time take another shot at it yet. I will post the solution as soon as I know more. Thanks a

Answer (score 0):

The ports 80 and 443 are the default ports used by the Nginx ingress, it was set in the values.yaml file of the nginx ingress charts. Generally, port 80 is for HTTP and the 443 for https. But if you want to change them as you want, you can set them when you install them via the helm like this:

```
--set controller.service.ports.http=8081 \
--set controller.service.ports.https=8082 \
```

The result shows here:

[image]

You can download the Nginx ingress charts and read the setting in it. Then you can change the setting as you want with the format above.

Comment: I want to whitelist some IPs for these new rules... at the NSG level (not at the ingress level).

Comment: @ThatChrisGuy Of course, it's already the NSG rules. Isn't this what you want?